# CODENVY: Is it possible to upload a jar file in java project?

Tags: codenvy

I am using **CODENVY** online IDE. I created a new java project .
I need to add new jar file in my class path . How can i add a new jar in class path.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, this can help you - http://docs.codenvy.com/user/technology-specific-features/#upload-local-libs

Basically, you need to upload a jar to your project and reference to it from your pom.xml.

If you want to run it like java -cp jar1:jar2, you will have to modify runtime a little bit, and run the commands from the terminal.

It will help if you elaborate on the use case. How would you do it locally?